# React Invisible reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, invisible-recaptcha

I am working with the react-google-recaptcha to implement the invisible ReCaptcha, passing a ref to the ReCAPTCHA component and executing `this._reCaptchaRef.current.execute()` inside the componentDidMount. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-invisbile-recaptcha showcases a form that makes use of the reCaptcha.

the onChange callback passed to the captcha component will set the value of the captcha into the state. The initial render the captcha value is set into the state and everything seems to work just fine, click on the **submit** button and the state value is printed onto the console.

After a few seconds, if we click on submit and look at the console, the value of the captcha is null. I tried to compare the value passed to onChange and if it was null I would invoke the 
`this._reCaptchaRef.current.execute()` but the issue raises when the value is null and we invoke the function but the first on `submit`, the value of captcha is null and every click from it will have the value in the state until it becomes null.

how do I invoke the Recaptcha for the submit button and also be able to pass the value of the captcha to the callback function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general idea is that the recaptcha token is valid only for a period of time. This is so that the tokens are not easily guessable by other computer systems.

Instead of doing the captcha on mount, you are supposed to execute it `onSubmit` only, hence the user would have filled the form when they see the captcha if at all.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this._reCaptchaRef.current.execute()
}
```

This would in turn trigger the `onChange` handler (or the `onError` handler) and you can submit the form from there.

But if you would like to somehow, keep it in `componentDidMount`, you can choose to reset the captcha and execute it again.

```
redoCaptcha() {
  this._reCaptchaRef.current.reset();
  this._reCaptchaRef.current.execute();
}
render() {
 ...
 <ReCAPTCHA
   onExpired={this.redoCaptcha}
 />
}
```

Comment: call the reset function in onChange after submitting the data to an endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

```
import ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha';

const DELAY = 1500;
class Form extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      load: false,
      expired: 'false',
      recaptchaLoaded: false
    };

    this._onSubmit = this._onSubmit.bind(this);
    this._reCaptchaRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({load: true});
    }, DELAY);
  }

sendData (endpoint, formData) {
    //--
    //---
    //---
    newFormData.append('recaptcha-token', this.state.value);
    //----
}

handleChange (value) {
  this.setState({value});
  if (this.state.value === null) this.setState({expired: 'true'});
}

asyncScriptOnLoad () {
  this.setState({recaptchaLoaded: true});
}

@validateAll
async _onSubmit (valid, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    await this._reCaptchaRef.current.executeAsync();
    //----
    //---
}

render () {
    {this.state.load && googleSiteKey && (
                  <ReCAPTCHA
                    style={{display: 'inline-block'}}
                    theme="dark"
                    size="invisible"
                    ref={this._reCaptchaRef}
                    sitekey={googleSiteKey}
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    asyncScriptOnLoad={this.asyncScriptOnLoad.bind(this)}
                  />
                )}
    <button className="cta--primary" disabled={!this.state.recaptchaLoaded}>{hasForm && (<Icon icon="rightarrow" fillColor="#fff" />)}{submit}</button>
    //------
    //---
}

module.exports = Form;

//-----------------------------------------------------
//for old react version remove React.createRef();
//add below line:

import ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha';

const DELAY = 1500;
class Form extends React.Component {
constructor (props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      load: false,
      expired: 'false',
      recaptchaLoaded: false
    };

    this._onSubmit = this._onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
componentDidMount () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({load: true});
    }, DELAY);
}
sendData (endpoint, formData) {
    //--
    //---
    //---
    const newFormData = new FormData();
    newFormData.append('recaptcha-token', this.state.value);
}

handleChange (value) {
    this.setState({value});
    if (this.state.value === null) this.setState({expired: 'true'});
}

asyncScriptOnLoad () {
    this.setState({recaptchaLoaded: true});
}

@validateAll
  async _onSubmit (valid, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    await this.recaptchaRef.executeAsync();
    //----
    //---
}

render () {
    {this.state.load && googleSiteKey && (
                  <ReCAPTCHA
                    style={{display: 'inline-block'}}
                    theme="dark"
                    size="invisible"
                    ref={(el) => { this.recaptchaRef = el; }}
                    sitekey={googleSiteKey}
                    onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                    asyncScriptOnLoad={this.asyncScriptOnLoad.bind(this)}
                  />
                )}
    <button className="cta--primary" disabled={!this.state.recaptchaLoaded}>{hasForm && (<Icon icon="rightarrow" fillColor="#fff" />)}{submit}</button>
    //------
    //---
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).